# How to accept id of social networks only "@" with javascript?

Tags: javascript

My form is like this

[image: social network]

After login a user, enter the id of social networks with `@` for example `@web` or `@test`...

How to create validate for show the user, for example:

> Please enter first with @, for example @test

blade

```
function showDynamicSocial() {
    let html = '' +
        '@foreach(auth()->user()->socials as $social)\n'+
        '<div class="col-md-6 position-relative">\n' +
        '<i class="fas fa-times text-danger position-absolute"></i>' +
        '<div class="row">\n' +
        '<div class="col-md-4">\n' +
        '<div class="form-group">\n' +
        '<label for="social_id">شبکه اجتماعی</label>\n' +
        '<select id="social_id" name="social_id[]" class="form-control">\n' +
        '@foreach($socials as $socialData)\n'+
        '<option value="{{ $socialData->id }}" {{ $socialData->id == $social->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>\n'+
        '{{ $socialData->name }}\n' +
        '</option>\n' +
        '@endforeach\n' +
        '</select>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">\n' +
        '<div class="form-group">\n' +
        '<label for="link">آی دی مرتبط</label>\n' +
        '<input id="link" value="{{ $social->pivot->link }}" name="link[]" class="form-control">\n' +
        '<br/><span class="linkErr"></span>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n ' +
        '@endforeach';
    $('#showSocial').append(html);
}
```

js

```
parent_fieldset.find('input[id="link"]').each(function() {
    var link;
    link = document.getElementById("link").value;
    var reg = /^@[a-zA-Z0-9\_\.\-]*$/;
    if (reg.test(link))
    {
        next_step = true;
    } else {
        next_step = false;
        let linkErrs = document.querySelectorAll(".linkErr");
        for(linkErr of linkErrs){
            linkErr.classList.add('alert', 'alert-danger');
            linkErr.textContent = "لطفا آیدی را با @ وارد کنید.";
        }

    }
});
```

Sorry, none of my JavaScript code is working.

If you help, it is appreciated.

**Note:** I do not see any error in this console.

Comment: First problem is you repeat all the element IDs. How does `document.getElementById` work if there are 10 elements with the same ID?

Comment: And why are you using `getElementById` inside a loop of `find` results anyway? Look up documentation on how `each` works, specifically values passed to the callback function.

Comment: Last of all, why is first code block using jQuery and then second goes back to browser methods?

Comment: @miken32 - What is the solution? Can you send complete the code. If you help, it is appreciated.